# extracting the error status/message from POST call in angular

Tags: angular, observable

I have a POST call to rest api from my angular service, and I want to return either the error status or the error message to do some logic on it, but am always getting [Object] as response (or undefined, depends on what I return from my error handling method) and I'm not managing to parse it!

From my service:

```
addDbResource(resource) {
   //console.log(JSON.stringify(resource));

    this.http.post(this.url + "resource", JSON.stringify(resource), this.options)
        //.map(this.extractData)
        .map(res => this.errorStatus = res)
        .catch(this.handleObservableError)
        .subscribe();

   return this.errorStatus;
}  


private handleObservableError (error: Response | any) {
    //console.error("Error1: " + error.message || error);
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
        error.status ? error.status + " - " + error.statusText : 'Server error';

    document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = error.json().message;

    return Observable.throw(error.status);
    //return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
    //return error.status;
}
```

PSB a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh86d.png)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add the `{observe:'response'}` property on your http post call ?

```
this.http.post(this.url + "resource", JSON.stringify(resource),{observe:'response'})
        //.map(this.extractData)
        .map(res => this.errorStatus = res)
        .catch(this.handleObservableError)
        .subscribe();
```

It will give you a complete Http response object with headers and the response status

Comment: I can't pass it as part pf parameters! getting:
Argument of type '{ observe: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'observe' does not exist in type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.

i tried as well adding it to the options object like this: this.headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                                     'Accept': 'application/json' });
      this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers , observe:'response'});
but didnt work as well

Comment: I don't understand why when I save the message or a status in global variable from inside the error handling method is not coming back to the calling method?! it's undefined! but when printing it to (console.log) from inside the error method it's there.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it at the end:

```
addDbResource(resource) {
   //console.log(JSON.stringify(resource));

    return this.http.post(this.url + "resource", JSON.stringify(resource), this.options)
        .catch(this.handleObservableError);
        //.subscribe();

   //More flexible approach
   /*return this.http.post(this.url + "resource", JSON.stringify(resource), this.options)
       .subscribe(response => {
            if (response.ok) { // <== CHECK Response status
                //this.data = response.json();
            } else {
                // handle bad request
            }
        },
        error => {
            this.errorMessage = <any>error;
            document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = error.json().message;
            console.log("-> " + error.status + " : " + this.errorMessage);
        });*/

}
```

and from the component that is calling the addResource method:

```
response.subscribe(res => {
        if (res.status == 200) window.location.href = "app/components/resourses-list";
        });
```

I realized that I cant save the data that I want from inside the subscribe and use it from outside after that.
The logic has to be inside the subscribe.